# logical replication Specific table error SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: postgresql

subscriber's log

```
2023-12-07 18:56:49.386 KST [1227687] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 1228473) exited with exit code 1
2023-12-07 18:56:49.423 KST [1228553] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "sub" has started
2023-12-07 19:00:15.063 KST [1228553] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
2023-12-07 19:00:15.072 KST [1227687] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 1228553) exited with exit code 1
2023-12-07 19:00:15.091 KST [1228609] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "sub" has started
```

logical replication Specific table error SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
This error does not occur in other tables

I use postgresql 15 subscriber and publisher

publisher .conf

```
# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 64MB           # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try           # on, off, or try
                    # (change requires restart)
#huge_page_size = 0         # zero for system default
                    # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB         # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0      # zero disables the feature
                    # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
work_mem = 4MB              # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 2.0      # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB        # min 1MB

max_wal_size = 40GB
min_wal_size = 30GB
max_wal_senders = 13    # max number of walsender processes
            # (change requires restart)
max_replication_slots = 13  # max number of replication slots
                # (change requires restart)
#wal_keep_size = 1000       # in megabytes; 0 disables
max_slot_wal_keep_size = -1 # in megabytes; -1 disables
#wal_sender_timeout = 900s  # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#track_commit_timestamp = off   # collect timestamp of transaction commit
```

subscriber's .conf

```
# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 128MB                  # min 128kB
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try                       # on, off, or try
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_page_size = 0                     # zero for system default
                                        # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB                     # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0          # zero disables the feature
                                        # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
#work_mem = 4MB                         # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 2.0              # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB            # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1               # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
logical_decoding_work_mem = 600MB       # min 64kB

max_wal_size = 10GB
min_wal_size = 5GB

#wal_receiver_timeout = 600s            # time that receiver waits for
                                        # communication from primary
                                        # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#wal_retrieve_retry_interval = 5s       # time to wait before retrying to
                                        # retrieve WAL after a failed attempt
#recovery_min_apply_delay = 0           # minimum delay for applying changes during recovery

# - Subscribers -

# These settings are ignored on a publisher.

max_logical_replication_workers = 20    # taken from max_worker_processes
                                        # (change requires restart)
max_sync_workers_per_subscription = 15
```

how can i fix error..?
I also changed the log level to info, but it doesn't record more detail logs

Comment: Is there a corresponding log message on the publisher? Does it make a difference if you increase `wal_sender_timeout` on the publisher?

Comment: after I set wal_sender_timeout, connection error is not occured. I think, it's problem is network problem. like bandwidth? i will test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If increasing `wal_sender_timeout` makes the problem go away, the SSL error is somewhat misleading: it just means that the primary server has closed the connection unexpectedly because there was no feedback from the client for a longer time.

There is no down side to increasing the timeout, except that it will take longer for the primary to react if the standby terminates irregularly.

Comment: Can i set wal_sender_timeout to 0 ??
Is there a problem when wal_sender_timeout is set to 0?

Comment: and When replicating more than three gigabytes of data, In susbcription log Like this 'could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer'

Comment: You cam set `wal_sender_timeout` to 0, sure."connection reset by peer" means that the other end hung up (look at the log) or that you have a broken network.

Comment: Thanks.. log is not too detailed.. how can i find detail log??

Comment: Look at the log file on both servers. If one of them hung up on the other, it did so because it encountered a problem, which it will log. If both think that the other one hung up on them, it is a broken network. Then maybe [keepalive can help you](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tcp-keepalive-for-a-better-postgresql-experience/).

Comment: Thank! I set the keepalive setting according to the data you told me, but it's the same

Comment: Then that is not your problem. I think we already determined that it is a timeout, not a network problem, right?

Comment: okok Thanks. How many hours does it take to replicate initial data? It's been over five hours, but it hasn't been replicated